# Can a random variable have the second order moment but not the mean?

Tags: probability, random-variables

Is it possible to have a random variable $Z$ for which the second order moment is well defined ($E[Z^2]$) while the mean ($E[Z]$) isn't?

If so, can I have an example? Otherwise, a proof why this is not possible?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! It would be helpful if you could extend your question by explaining what you mean by well-defined and telling us your own suspicions.

Comment: I was suspicious the quantity E[Z^2] could be finite and E[Z] infinite but the answer by drhab proves it is not possible

Comment: It is possible to have $E[Z^2]=+\infty$ while $E[Z]$ cannot be coherently defined (due to $\infty - \infty$ issues). But if $Z$ is a r.v. and $E[Z^2]<\infty$ then $E[Z]$ exists as a finite number. (Also, it is possible that $Z^2$ is a r.v. and $Z$ is not, such as if $Z=1_N - 1_{N^c}$ where $N$ is some nonmeasurable subset of $\Omega$. This is usually artificial, though.)

Answer (score 1):

No.

$$|Z|\leq1+Z^2\implies\mathbb E|Z|\leq1+\mathbb EZ^2$$ This guarantees that $\mathbb EZ$ is well defined if $\mathbb EZ^2<\infty$

Comment: thank you for your answer!

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: And in general $(\mathbb E |Z|^k)^{1/k} \le (\mathbb E |Z|^{k+1})^{1/(k+1)}$.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. More generally, if you have a $p$-th moment, you have a $r$-th moment for $r\leq p$.

This means that if $r\leq p$, then $E[|X|^p]<+\infty\implies E[|X|^r]<+\infty$.

*Proof*: Assume $E[|X|^p]<+\infty$ and $r\leq p$.

$y\mapsto y^{\frac{p}{r}}$ is convex over $\mathbb{R}_+$. This implies, by Jensen's inequality, that if $Y$ is a non-negative random variable, $E[Y]^{\frac{p}{r}}\leq E[Y^{\frac{p}{r}}]$. Now let $Y=|X|^r$. We get:
$$E[|X|^r]^{\frac{p}{r}}\leq E[|X|^p]<+\infty$$
Hence $E[|X|^r]<+\infty$.

Be aware that this property does not hold in general $L^p$ spaces, but only if the measure is finite (which is of course the case of probability spaces).

Another proof: $E[|X|^r]=\int_{\Omega}|X|^rdP=\int_{|X|\leq 1}|X|^rdP+\int_{|X|> 1}|X|^rdP$.

Then $\int_{|X|\leq 1}|X|^rdP\leq \int_{|X|\leq 1}1dP=P(|X|\leq 1)\leq 1$.

And $\int_{|X|> 1}|X|^rdP\leq \int_{|X|> 1}|X|^pdP\leq E[|X^p|]<+\infty$. Hence $E[|X|^r]<+\infty$.

Here again, we use the finiteness of a probability measure.